# Rails joins polymorphic model attribute where condition is met

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, polymorphic-associations

I can't figure out how to make this query work. I'm looking to get all the user ids of addresses who have a user that is an admin.

```
Address
.near([@address.latitude, @address.longitude], 5)
.where(addressable_type: 'User')
.joins(:addressable)
.where('addressable.is_admin = ?', true)
.pluck(:id)
```

Address.rb

```
class Address < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :addressable, polymorphic: true
```

User.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :address, :as => :addressable, dependent: :destroy
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot directly join the `addressable` relation as the addressable entities could belong to different models. You could try something like this:

```
Address
  .near([@address.latitude, @address.longitude], 5)
  .where(addressable_type: 'User')
  .joins("INNER JOIN users on users.id = addresses.addressable_id")
  .merge(User.admin)
  .pluck(:id)
```

`.merge` can be used to invoke scopes of joined tables. Here, `User` model would have a scope called `admin` which would return admin users.

Comment: Actually the merge seems not to be doing anything. the pluck collects the id of the addresses, not the users.

Comment: You would have to use `.pluck(:user_id)` to pluck user ids of the addresses that have been fetched

Comment: Also, for `.merge` to have any effect, you would have to declare a scope on `User` called `admin` which would get the admin users. 
`scope :admin, -> () { is_admin: true }` on `app/models/user.rb`

Comment: Did that help ?

Comment: I did that, but the merge still does not have any effect.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. The join with users should have been an "INNER JOIN" instead of a "LEFT JOIN". Also, could you please add the `to_sql` result of the query above? (You'll have to run `.to_sql` by removing the `pluck` part.)

Comment: It works with the INNER JOIN. Thank you for your time!